# PHP Write File Error

Tags: php, file

I have a page called index.php which is calling a function "writelog" in includes/Logger.php

I have file located at includes folder and code is as below.

```
function writelog($logText){
            $myFile = "testlog.txt";
            $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
            $stringData = $logText + "\n";
            fwrite($fh, $stringData);
            fclose($fh);
}
```

It shows errror "can't open file" . I have set FullPermission for everyone and still it says it cant access file.I tried to put file in same folder as index.php and same error. What can be possible cause ? Am I having wrong path ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the full path of the log file

`$myFile = "/full/path/to/testlog.txt";`

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming this file is also in includes, I'm guessing this is called from another script so the path would be one of the calling script. You can use this:
    `$prevdir = getcwd();
    chdir(dirname(__FILE__));
    $myFile = "testlog.txt";
    chdir($prevdir);`

But it's best to use absolute paths